# Can't see the button

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibutton

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    int leftBorder = 80;
    int topBorder = 160;
    int width = 150;
    int height = 50;
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(leftBorder, topBorder, width, height)];
    myView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];  

    UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    testButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    [testButton setTitle:@"testButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.myView addSubview:self.testButton];

    self.myView.hidden = YES;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Hi, sorry for stupid question! I'm newby in xcode. Why I didn't see this button? And How can I hide button after click? I need button inside the frame.

Comment: You are adding your button to `myView` and then hiding `myView` which contains the button inside it.

Comment: you dont see it because you hide the view: self.myView.hidden = YES;

Comment: Another comment: you're using `int` to construct a `CGRect`, you should use `CGFloat` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple remove `self.myView.hidden = YES;`

To add you click listener, two solution:

By code in your viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

-  (void)myButtonClick:(id)sender {
    myButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

Or via interface Builder (preferred), The easiest way is to actually define the handler/action in Xcode using the IBAction declaration in the interface file (add the declaration just before the @end statement). Then attach the action to the button

Comment: This is right but it alone will not help. He still messes around with ivars and locals.

Comment: @gomino Sorry, i'm new at stackoverflow. Thank you for helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

- you are adding self.testButton instead of the created testButton.

  ```
  [self.myView addSubview:testButton];
  ```
- you did not assign myView to your property.

  ```
  [self.view addSubview:myView]; self.myView = myView;
  ```
- remove self.myView.hidden = YES;

Another remark:
You should usually call super as early as possible. Otherwise, the superclass may interfere with your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code.

1. You add `testButton` as subview to `self.myView`. Then you hide `self.myView`. As a result neither `self.myview` nor its subviews will be visible.
2. You get confused with your local varialbles and instance varialbes. Apparently there is an instance variable and property `myView`. Otherwise you coudn't use `self.myView`. And you declare a local variable `myView`, which is not the same as the instance variable. This may well be perfectly ok. But I got a guts feeling that you did this not intentionally. Your `self.myView` may well be nil at the point in time where you add the subview. And even the subview `self.testButton` may be nil. That will compile file and execute fine but nothing does happen actually.
3. The same for testButton.

I suggest to change the code a bit, assuming there are properties for myView and testButton of the appropriate types:

```
self.myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(leftBorder, topBorder, width, height)];
self.myView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
self.myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.myView]; 

self.testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
self.testButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[self.testButton setTitle:@"testButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.myView addSubview:self.testButton];

self.myView.hidden = NO;
```